# Filter search in Laravel 5.2

Tags: search, laravel-5, filtering, laravel-query-builder

I am creating a Search Filter in a project using Laravel 5.2. I tried for 2/3 days but cannot figure out how the query structure should be. Here is the Blade for filter

```
<form class="resume_filters in_sidebar" action="{{ action('FrontController@candidates') }}" method="get">

<!-- Location -->
<div class="widget">
    <h4>Location</h4>
    <div class="search_location">
        <input type="text" name="search_location" id="search_location" placeholder="Location"/>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Skills -->
<div class="widget">
    <h4>Filter by Skills</h4>
    <div class="search_categories resume-filter">
        {!! Form::select('search_skills[]',$repository->filterSkills($candidates),null,['id'=>'search_skills','class'=>'chosen-select','multiple'=>'multiple']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Sub Category -->
<div class="widget">
    <h4>Filter by Categories</h4>
    <div class="search_categories resume-filter">
        {!! Form::select('search_categories[]',$repository->filterSubCategory($candidates),null,['id'=>'search_categories','class'=>'job-manager-category-dropdown','multiple'=>'multiple']) !!}                 
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="button big" value="Filter" />

</form>
```

The search criteria is:

1. If filter by only one item (location or skills or categories) it will search only in that column and ignore other columns.
2. If filter by two items it should match both column and ignore other.
3. If filter by three/all it should match three columns.

I tried it in many different ways, my controller code is really messed up. So, I'm not posting it right now. Can anyone please help to build the query for filtering?

Answer (score 0):

How about using conditionals on your controller checking which field is filled? So you can execute the proper query based on the current state of the search form.

Comment: There are three input fields. If I check them one by one and check for two and check if three fields are filled or not,  I will have to write too much code.

Comment: I think it's easier on the machine and the code will be more maintainable than to set the conditionals on the query part, though; cmiiw.

Comment: OK, let me try. I'll keep updating my progress. Thank You.